# Фокус поля в ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

Здравствуйте. Никак не получается сделать фокус текстового поля в форме окна. Простое окно авторизации с двумя полями и кнопкой. Что я только не делал. Фокус мистически очень редко работает. Он появляется, сразу сбрасывается и поле становится красным (из-за валидации). Вроде как нужно делать так:

```
...
thisObject.loginField=Ext.create("Ext.form.TextField",{
fieldLabel: 'Логин',
id: 'auth-login',
validator:function (value) {
    if (value.length<3 || value.length>128)
        return 'Длина строки должна быть не меньше 3 и не больше 128 символов';
    else if (!value.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/i))
        return 'Строка должна содержать только латинские буквы, цифры, и символ подчеркивания';
    else return true;
 },
  listeners: {
      afterrender: function(field) {
          field.focus(true);
      },
      specialkey: function(f,e){
           if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                //обработка нажатия
                thisObject.Authorization();
           }
      }
  }
...
```

[Справка](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-focus):
    focus([selectText],[delay]) - принимает должен ли выделяться текст при фокусу, если есть и задержка.
Пробовал все комбинации параметров. Никак не хочет работать.

П.С. Весь код класса вот: [http://pastebin.com/2K3pjHwW](URL)

Окно создаю так:

```
    <script>
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        var login_window = Ext.create('Ext.LoginWindow');
        login_window.ShowWindow();
    });
    </script>
```

После смены пространства имен. Вроде работает так:

```
field.focus(false,100);
```

Если не 100, то не работает.

Comment: Жесть. Народ, помогите. Не заставляйте пользоваться найденным решением:  
  
    setTimeout(function(){
         field.focus(true);
    },100);
  
Оно конечно работает(хоть и поле красным подсвечивается), но блин...

Answer (score 2):

Когда решил выложить код создания окна, то понял, что пространоство имен MyDesktop можно убрать, т.к. окно сначала было в рабочем столе, а потом вынесено отдельно и пространства MyDesktop не стало. Поменял на Ext.LoginWindow и код с таймаутом начал работать без подсветки поля "красным". Впринципе конечно можно оставить, но это как-то неправильно...